# Logic for reading rows and columns from a text file (textparser) C++

Tags: c++

I'm really stuck with this problem I'm having for reading rows and columns from a text file. We're using text files that our prof gave us. I have the functionality running so when the user in puts "numrows (file)" the number of rows in that file prints out.

However, every time I enter the text files, it's giving me 19 for both. The first text file only has 4 rows and the other one has 7. I know my logic is wrong, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here's what I have for the numrows function:

```
int numrows(string line) {
 ifstream ifs;
 int i;
 int row = 0;
 int array [10] = {0};
 while (ifs.good()) {
    while (getline(ifs, line)) {
           istringstream stream(line);
           row = 0;
           while(stream >>i) {
           array[row] = i;
           row++;


        }

    }
  }
    }
```

and here's the numcols:

```
int numcols(string line) {
int col = 0;
int i;
int arrayA[10] = {0};
ifstream ifs;
while (ifs.good()) {
    istringstream streamA(line);
    col = 0;
    while (streamA >>i){
        arrayA[col] = i;
        col++;
    }

}
```

}

edit: @chris yes, I wasn't sure what value to return as well. Here's my main:

```
int main() {

string fname, line;
ifstream ifs;
cout << "---- Enter a file name : ";                                        
while (getline(cin, fname)) { // Ctrl-Z/D to quit!                          
    // tries to open the file whose name is in string fname  
    ifs.open(fname.c_str());
        if(fname.substr(0,8)=="numrows ") {
            line.clear();
            for (int i = 8; i<fname.length(); i++) {
                line = line+fname[i];
            }
            cout << numrows (line) << endl;
            ifs.close();

        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: These functions don't appear to be `return`ing anything - you should change that, at least, if you want to stay with this implementation, but I think your code doesn't do anything at all. I'm curious as to how you're getting a value of 19. Can we see your `main()`?

Comment: that was another problem as well. i had no idea what to return in the first place. i've added my main. also, to answer your other question: yes, the user must input "numcols (filename)" or "numrows (filename)" so the result will be the number of columns or rows are within each file. i'm totally stuck on the logic of it.

Comment: Does this actually open a file? My guess is 'pretty unlikely'... You're trying to open something called (for example) "numrows myFile.txt", and I'd guess you instead want to open just "myFile.txt"

Comment: i doubt it as well. i thought the ifs.open/ifs.close functions would work, but no matter what file i put, i get "19". the user must input "numrows" to get the number of rows and same for columns. it's the requirements of the lab. should i change the logic for the functions of numrows/cols? i think that's the problem. just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You have two options here really - the first is to create two programs, one with an executable called "numrows", and the other "numcols", and have both of them read from `argv[]` (google is your friend :) ). The second, and maybe more appropriate option, is to have only one program which parses input, as you have (sort of) - but you want to parse the input before trying to open a file. Consider asking for a filename separately to an operation, or if you must take them together, then split them before opening the file, or running a function

Comment: so do i need to change my logic for the functions? or is the logic okay? i don't mind parsing the input before opening file.

Comment: This question seems to be several part-questions. I think that my answer is pretty comprehensive now, but if you need more details, perhaps asking a number of smaller questions would be more suitable? You could edit links to them into this question and I'll look at them, but now the answer is a large block of text and likely addressing too many issues to be quickly of use to other readers.

Comment: What is the format of the input file?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be more easily solved by opening the text file as an `ifstream`, and then using  [`std::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) to process your input.

You can try for comparison against '\n' as the end of line character, and implement a pair of counters, one for columns on a line, the other for lines.

If you have variable length columns, you might want to store the values of (numColumns in a line) in a [`std::vector<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), using `myVector.push_back(numColumns)` or similar.

Both links are to the cplusplus.com/reference section, which can provide a large amount of information about C++ and the STL.

**Edited-in overview of possible workflow**

You want one program, which will take a filename, and an 'operation', in this case "numrows" or "numcols". As such, your first steps are to find out the filename, and operation.

Your current implementation of this (in your question, after editing) won't work. Using `cin` should however be fine. Place this earlier in your `main()`, before opening a file.

Use substr like you have, or alternatively, search for a space character. Assume that the input after this is your filename, and the input in the first section is your operation. Store these values.

After this, try to open your file. If the file opens successfully, continue. If it won't open, then complain to the user for a bad input, and go back to the beginning, and ask again.

Once you have your file successfully open, check which type of calculation you want to run. Counting a number of rows is fairly easy - you can go through the file one character at a time, and count the number that are equal to '\n', the line-end character. Some files might use carriage-returns, line-feeds, etc - these have different characters, but are both a) unlikely to be what you have and b) easily looked up!

A number of columns is more complicated, because your rows might not all have the same number of columns. If your input is `1 25 21 abs 3k`, do you want the value to be 5? If so, you can count the number of space characters on the line and add one. If instead, you want a value of 14 (each character and each space), then just count the characters based on the number of times you call `get()` before reaching a '\n' character. The use of a vector as explained below to store these values might be of interest.

Having calculated these two values (or value and set of values), you can output based on the value of your 'operation' variable. For example,

```
if (storedOperationName == "numcols") {
    cout<< "The number of values in each column is " << numColsVal << endl;
}
```

If you have a vector of column values, you could output all of them, using

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < numColsVal.size(); pos++) {
    cout<< numColsVal[pos] << " ";
}
```

Following all of this, you can return a value from your `main()` of `0`, or you can just end the program (C++ now considers no return value from main to a be a return of 0), or you can ask for another filename, and repeat until some other method is used to end the program.

**Further details**

`std::get()` with no arguments will return the next character of an `ifstream`, using the example code format

```
std::ifstream myFileStream;
myFileStream.open("myFileName.txt");
nextCharacter = myFileStream.get(); // You should, before this, implement a loop.
// A possible loop condition might include something like `while myFileStream.good()`
// See the linked page on std::get()
if (nextCharacter == '\n')
{ // You have a line break here }
```

You could use this type of structure, along with a pair of counters as described earlier, to count the number of characters on a line, and the number of lines before the EOF (end of file).

If you want to store the number of characters on a line, for each line, you could use

```
std::vector<int> charPerLine;
int numberOfCharactersOnThisLine = 0;
while (...)
{
   numberOfCharactersOnThisLine = 0
   // Other parts of the loop here, including a numberOfCharactersOnThisLine++; statement
   if (endOfLineCondition)
   {
       charPerLine.push_back(numberOfCharactersOnThisLine); // This stores the value in the vector
   }
}
```

You should `#include` `<vector>` and either specific `std::` before, or use a `using namespace std;` statement near the top. People will advise against using namespaces like this, but it can be convenient (which is also a good reason to avoid it, sort of!)

Comment: sorry, i'm a huge beginner at c++ so i'm not sure what you mean by using `std::get`? is that a function of some sorts?

Comment: Exactly :) I'll edit the answer to be a little more explicit. Are you able to pass the filename to your program from the command line? Your question makes that look like a requirement for your hw